# Multiple Websites and Sitemap XML

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps

I have multiple websites with different domains for each website and different Catalog Root Tree for each website on a single Magento 1.9 installation.

The first website (abc.com) is the default website store selling almost 40.000 products. The second website (123.com) have a limited range with same product of first website.

When I create a product I select the website that I want to show the product (or select all websites). Also If I select all website I choose to add it to specific category of every website.

I create different sitemaps for every store view of every website.

The problem is that to second sitemap xml (with limited range of products) appears all the products even if I haven't enabled. As a result the Google returns me 404 error cause not find the product.

Anyone know how can I exclude the products from the second XML?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set different name for 123.com sitemap and describe it to robots.txt

If you use same name "sitemap.xml" sitemap for 123.com is overrided by default abc.com sitemap.

Comment: Hi @Bashev. The problem is  the generation of sitemap.xml. The sitemap contains products that isn't enabled to website.